# What makes VIM such a powerful text editor?

Tags: macos, vim, development

I read around around the web and many people tend to praise emacs and VIM for their power and versatibility.

But to keep things more specific I want to focus on VIM.

What makes it so versatile? What features make it so powerful? Is it there something in specific that makes user love it so much?

Or is it the simple fact that it has been around for so long that there's a ton of support for it and a colossal amount of plug-ins have been developed for it?

Comment: What's so special about VIM text editor is really a matter of opinion. Check out the `customization` section of [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vim_(text_editor)). It'open source FREE as well. What makes it "special" to one person may not make it special to another person.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

VIM - the power - the prestige!

**VIM Edit**: 

What's good about VIM: VIM is a verbose terminal command line interface tool. VIM allows you to keep your hands at the keyboard without interruptions with the mouse. It is a shortcut power tool. BUT, you have to be really good and have a lot of practice to make this a valid statement.

Here is a cheat sheet (there are Many): [CHEAT SHEET VIM](http://vim.rtorr.com/)

**VIM Compile**: 

You can also compile your code without leaving the interface.

**VIM Run**: 

Run your code from the interface.

**Open Source**:
Linux flavours are abundant and have a community of masters that contribute to keeping it viable and stable. Without these key people Linux wouldn't be where it is. You can purchase Linux versions with dedicated support. But it's the Open Source that is becoming the norm -- that goes with free Apps (applications) created from Open Source software.

* Note: 

eMac, Macbook, Mac, (Apple that is) have been around for a very long time and the native language is that of Unix or a flavour of Linux. So with Apple/Mac you don't have to create a virtual partition or dual boot, just use the terminal as if you were in a Unix/Linux machine. That's the cohesiveness of it.

I come from a long life of PC and a super user of shortcuts and DOS command line interfacing and Windows versions of compilers. And so learning VIM was a challenge. But if you come from the Mac generation, then moving to Linux isn't as much of a learning curve as coming from PC. Especially learning what /root or /etc meant, because coming from PC it's C:/ or My Documents...

Answer (score 1):

In short: It is very keyboard driven (In fact you don't need the mouse).
I prefer emacs, but this argument is also valid for vim.
I think this is the core, but you could further argue that both are highly configurable.

Comment: Why do you prefer emacs over vim?

Comment: I think it's mostly personal flavour.  Also I am used to the key bindings and I like lisp.